# How to search (TRUE/FALSE) for a term from a list of websites?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, excel-automation, vba

I have a column of URLs in an Excel spreadsheet. I'd like to enter a word somewhere (a cell off to the right or a dialog box) and have Excel search all the URLs in the column (or a subset of them) for that term. It should work in the background, that is, without opening a browser. I'd like it to output TRUE or FALSE depending if that term is found in each webpage in the column. Ideally, it would return TRUE or FALSE in the box to the right of the URL, or, even better, it would turn the cell a color.

Super-bonus: the process can show its progress and can be broken by the user.

I would especially appreciate help in copying a webpage's text into a String. I think I could figure out the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for recommendations, tutorials, research, tools, libraries, and code are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To find the text in the cell you can use a formula, and fill down. Assuming URLS are in column A, enter in the cell to the right.

```
=IF(FIND("Text to find", A1), "True", "False")
```

Use conditional formatting to change the cell colour based on the result.

You can use a web query to get the text from the webpage.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba